# Properties of tangent line at a point of a differentiable curve $y=f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let a function $\mathrm{P}:[0,1]\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable in $(0,1)$ and continuous at $0$ and $1 .$ Define a map $\mathrm{H}: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ by $\mathrm{H}(x)=\mathrm{P}(0)+(\mathrm{P}(1)-\mathrm{P}(0))x .$ Show that for every $\mathrm{r}>1$ there exist a point $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that the tangent line to $\mathrm{y}=\mathrm{P}(x)$ at point $(\mathrm{c}, \mathrm{P}(\mathrm{c}))$
passes through the point $(r, H(r))$

How to say that for any $r>1$ there is a line $y=P'(c)x+(P(c)-cP'(c))$for some $c\in (0,1)$ satisfies $(r,H(r))$

Comment: Please typeset the math properly in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired result amounts to finding $c\in (0,1)$ such that

$$\tag 1 P'(c)= \frac{P(c)-H(r)}{c-r}.$$

Define

$$\tag 2 f(x)=\frac{P(x)-H(r)}{x-r},\, x\in [0,1].$$

Note $f(0)=f(1).$ Thus Rolle's theorem gives $c\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0.$ Use the quotient rule on $(2)$ to see $f'(c)=0$ implies $(1).$