# Derivative of a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Given a function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and continuous at $0$ and $1$. Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the line which passes through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. I was wondering how to show that for every $s \notin [a,b]$, there exists $t \in [a,b]$ such that the tangent line of $f(x)$ at the point $(t,f(t))$ passes throught $(s,g(s))$? (I was thinking of using Mean Value Theorem, but I failed to prove it by only using MVT.)

Comment: This is called Flett's Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846057/properties-of-tangent-line-at-a-point-of-a-differentiable-curve-y-fx-on-0/3847708#3847708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, $f(a)=f(b)=0$ because we can subtract from $f$ a linear function without breaking the tangency condition. Now consider the auxiliary function

$$\frac{f(t)}{t-s}$$ that has the derivative

$$\frac{f'(t)(t-s)-f(t)}{(t-s)^2}$$ canceling where

$$f'(t^*)=\frac{f(t^*)}{t^*-s}$$
and apply Rolle's theorem.